# Stored Connection Strings per user

Tags: vb.net, string, dynamic, connection

In the past I've used a Singleton Pattern to load the connection string when the application starts via the global.asa file.

I have a project now where each user has a unique connection string to the database.  I would like to load this connection string once.  The issue is that the singleton pattern will not work for me since each user has there own connection string.  Basically the connection string is created dynamically.

I do not want to store it is session.  If anyway has a clever way of doing this in .NET let me know ?

Comment: How are you using the connection string?

Comment: We are taking the existing connection string. Then replacing the USER ID and Password with a specific one that is stored in the database.  This is so we can track each user that logins to the database.  I wish I could set the connection string one time when the user logins and jsut have my code call it when needed.  I don't want to have to constantly build it each time I need it.

Answer (score 2):

Connections to the database are quite expensive, in terms of resources, and I personally would suggest that you reconsider your requirements of having one per user. Unless you can guarantee that the total number of users is going to be very small (say no more than 5-10).

Having said that, you can just store the connection in the `User` object that represents your user. Or have a global dictionary that maps user ids to connection strings.

If the only difference between the connection strings is the username/password, you could consider impersonating the client and using Windows authentication in SQL Server instead.

Comment: What do you mean in the USER object ? Right now the USERID is stored in session.  I don't want to store the connection sting in session.